# For matrices $2 \times 2$, conditions for $A$ such that $tr(XAY^{T})$ is an inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products

Given a generic $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$:

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
  a&b\\
  c&d
\end{array}
\right] $$

the exercise is to determine conditions for $a$, $d$ and $b-c$ such that $tr(XAY^{T})$ is an inner product.

Verifying linearity and symmetry we get $b=c$.

My problem is verifying the positive-definite propertie. I arrived at the expression, where $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ are the elements of the matrix $X$:

$tr(XAX^{T}) = a(x_1^2+x_3^2) + d(x_2^2+x_4^2) + (b+c)(x_1x_2 + x_3x_4)$

but was unable to analyse the conditions $a$ and $d$ should satisfie.

Comment: wait, are you sure X and Y must be matrices? and be careful, you want $tr(XAY^T)$ to be a inner product, not  $tr(XAX^T)$

Comment: I am sure that X and Y are $2 \times 2$ matrices and I wrote $tr(XAX^{T})$ to verify the positive-definite propertie.

Comment: Hint: by considering $x_1=1$ and all the others to $0$, show that $a$ (and similarly $d$) must be positive. Then, you get a constraint on $b+c=2b$ by setting $x_3=x_4=0$, namely $2\sqrt{ad} > 2|b|$, ie $ad-bc > 0$. So “$A$ is symmetric positive semidefinite” is a necessary condition.

Answer (score 3):

For the positive-definite part, suppose that $A$ is not positive definite. Then there exists nonzero $z\in\mathbb R^2$ such that $t=z^TAz\leq0$. So
$$
\operatorname{Tr}(zz^TAzz^T)=t\,\operatorname{Tr}(zz^T)\leq0,
$$
since $\operatorname{Tr}(zz^T)\geq0$.

Answer (score 0):

Completing the square should help here.  For instance,
\begin{align*}
    ax_1^2 + d x_2^2 + 2bx_1x_2 &= a\left(x_1 + \frac{b}{a}x_2\right)^2 + \left(d - \frac{b^2}{a}\right)x_3^2
\end{align*}
You want the coefficients of the squares on the right to be positive.

Answer (score 0):

> $tr(XAX^{T}) = a(x_1^2+x_3^2) + d(x_2^2+x_4^2) + (b+c)(x_1x_2 + x_3x_4)$

$tr(XAX^{T}) = a(x_1^2+x_3^2) + d(x_2^2+x_4^2) + (2b)(x_1x_2 + x_3x_4)=PAP^T+QAQ^T$

where $P=(x_1,x_2)$ and $Q=(x_3,x_4)$

For $tr(XAX^{T})\ge 0$ you need  both the terms on right side individually $\ge 0$ for which you must have $A$ to be positive definite. Using Sylvester criterion of positive definite:

$a>0$ and $ad-b^2>0\implies d>b^2/a>0$